# Baeyer-Villiger Oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there any logical reasoning behind the migratory aptitude for different groups in Baeyer-Villiger Oxidation? 
Like in pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement, hydride ion is a better migrating group than an aryl which is better than an alkyl group. But why isn't this kind of order in Baeyer-Villiger Oxidation?